# Write program to download .gz file in java?

Tags: java

I've been trying to write a program in java that can download a number of .gz files from an ftp server online for me. Here's what I've been using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/geo/DATA/SOFT/by_series/GSE10/");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("GSE10_family.soft.gz");

    int i = 0;
    byte[] bytesIn = new byte[3000000];
    while ((i = in.read(bytesIn)) >= 0) {
        out.write(bytesIn, 0, i);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
```

The program runs and downloads the file just fine. However, when I try to uncompress the .gz file, it unzips as a .cpgz file which then creates an endless cycle of .cpgz to .gz and so forth.

When I download this file manually, it unzips and everything perfectly fine, so I know it isn't a problem with the file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: It looks to me like you are downloading the entire folder and saving it as a gzip file.  Shouldn't you have the file name on the server in there somewhere?

Comment: if your question has been answered, please mark the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I print out the contents of the file you download it appears as

```
-r--r--r--   1 ftp      anonymous  2311751 Jan 29 16:45 GSE10_family.soft.gz
```

If I download the file instead of the directory I get a gzip file.

```
$ gunzip GSE10_family.soft.gz

$ ls -l GSE10_family.soft
----------+ 1 peter None 7698802 2011-06-09 16:24 GSE10_family.soft
```

Answer (score 0):

Not super pretty but will have the job done

```
void downloadGzip(String dir, String url, String user, String pwd) throws Exception {



    //Authentication
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pwd);
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(new URI(url).getHost(), AuthScope.ANY_PORT), creds);
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(new HttpGet(url), context);

    //get remote file name
    Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Content-Disposition");
    String file = headers[0].getValue().substring(headers[0].getValue().lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
    String out = dir + file.substring(0, file.indexOf(".gz"));

    GzipCompressorInputStream stream = new GzipCompressorInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, new File(out));
    stream.close();
}
```